# In an arithmetic series find the least number of terms k that must be taken so that Sk > 559

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

$T_{10}=37,S_5=45$ therefore $a=1$ and $d=4.$

Trying to find $k$:

$S_n= \frac{n}{2}(2(1) + (n-1)4 ) > 559$

$4n^2 - 2n > 1118$

How do I finish this inequality to find the least number of n?

Comment: Consider the quadratic equation first. Find the roots and then .... ???

Comment: please consider using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: TheSimpliFire- sorry I don't understand MathJax :(
 Claude Leibovici - will i make 4n^2 - 2n = 0 ?

Comment: @NadiaKuznecova, please take some time to learn it if you are going to post more on this site. It really isn't that complicated.

Comment: I've tried reading over it few times but it doesn't make much sense... looks like some programming stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$4n^2-2n>1118$$

$$4n^2-2n+\frac{1}{4}>1118+\frac{1}{4}$$

$$(2n-\frac{1}{2})^2>1118+\frac{1}{4}$$

$33^2=1089$, $34^2=1156$

$$2n-\frac{1}{2}>33.4$$

$$2n>33.9$$

$$n>16.95$$

i.e. $$n=17$$

Comment: how did you simplify to (2n+1/2)^2? and why did you add a 1/4?

Comment: To form the expression of the form $(a+b)^2$. I used $a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2$

Comment: why is b = 1/2 ?

Comment: aa ok i see b^2 is 1/4 so b is 1/2

Comment: how did you know to add 1/4 at the start? can you add any number?

Comment: No, You have to add $b^2$ such that you get the form $a^2+2ab+b^2$. For a trick always add square of the half of the second term. i.e. if you have, $x^2+16xy$, add square of half of the second term i.e $(\frac{16y}{2})^2$

Comment: but here the second term was 2, and 2/2^2 is not 1/4.. im still confused how you got 1/4. I understand what you are saying above but it doesnt seem to match this example

Comment: ok so finally got it... 2= 2ab since a^2 =4n^2
2(4)(1/4) = 2 so b=1/4

Comment: @NadiaKuznecova, Read this [article](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/completing-square.html) for more clarification. Message me if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

[For finding roots it might be handy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2mlL.gif) 
As you already reached till the quadratic equation, the next part is to find the roots
after solving the equation, we get roots as 16.97 and -16.47

so expression will be (k-16.97)(k+16.47)>0

that indicates us k should be either greater than 16.97 or less than -16.47, as k is the number of terms it can't be negative and the least integer greater than 16.97 would be 17.

So you need to take 17 terms so as to make the sum greater than 559 And if you check, 
$S_{17}$=561 which satisfies the condition.

Comment: how do you find the roots?

Comment: which formula? what squaring method? if I knew all this I wouldn't be asking!

Comment: thanks for those formulas! would 'c' in the formula be equal to 1118?

Comment: yea a=4,b=-2,c=-1118